# How to handle observable of array

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, rxjs

I am working in an angular app that retrives a collection from firebase(Observable<any[]>), then for each element of that collection map a new object based on the original value plus informacion from another firebase collection.

```
 getLoans(estadoPrestamo: boolean){
return this.afs.collection<any>('prestamos', ref => ref.where('devuelto', '==', estadoPrestamo)).valueChanges()
  .pipe(
    map(p => p.map(x => ({...x,usuarioCompleto: this.obtainUserInfo(x.usuario).subscribe(data => {return data;})}))),
    tap(data => console.log(data))
  );

   obtainUserInfo(usuarioId: string){
    console.log(usuarioId);
    try{
      return this.afs.doc<any>('users/' +usuarioId).valueChanges().pipe(
        tap(x => console.log(x))
      );
    }
    catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
    }
  }
```

I have tried variations of above code with no luck. getLoan() method must return an observable<any[]>.
Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

you need to use a higher order operator like `switchMap` to handle the inner subscribe for you, and you'll also need to use `combineLatest` to combine all the inner observables.

```
getLoans(estadoPrestamo: boolean){
  // get your collection
  return this.afs.collection<any>('prestamos', ref => ref.where('devuelto', '==', estadoPrestamo)).valueChanges()
  .pipe(
    // switchMap into combineLatest of array mapped into 
    // inner observables that map into the complete object
    switchMap(p => combineLatest(
      ...p.map(x => this.obtainUserInfo(x.usuario).pipe(
        map(usarioComplete => ({...x, usarioComplete}))
      ))
    ))
  )
);
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response, but I am getting the following error "Type 'OperatorFunction<any, unknown>' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<any>'.
  Property '[Symbol.iterator]' is missing in type 'OperatorFunction<any, unknown>' but required in type 'Iterable<any>'"